# Multi-Org Android Configuration Microsoft MDM Intune

Tags: single-sign-on, mobile, saml, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I am trying to configure Intune MDM (Mobile Data Management) to push multiple instances of Salesforce in the app config. Intune provide a JSON configuration for Android for Works and a XML configuration for iOS.

While I have success with a iOS XML Multi-Org configuration that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"
"http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>AppServiceHosts</key>
<array>
<string>MyCustomDomain1.my.saleforce.com</string>
<string>MyCustomDomain2.my.salesforce.com</string>

</array>
<key>AppServiceHostLabels</key>
<array>
<string>My Custom Domain 1</string>
<string>My Custom Domain 2</string>
</array>
<key>RequireCertAuth</key>
<true/>
<key>ClearClipboardOnBackground</key>
<false/>
<key>OnlyShowAuthorizedHosts</key>
<false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have no success to adding more than one instance with Android for works, here is a working example, but I would like to add MyCustomDomain2:

```
{
"kind": "androidenterprise#managedConfiguration",
"productId": "app:com.salesforce.chatter",
"managedProperty": [
{
"key": "RequireCertAuth",
"valueBool": true
},
{
"key": "AppServiceHosts",
"valueString": "https://MyCustomDomain1.my.saleforce.com"
},
{
"key": "OnlyShowAuthorizedHosts",
"valueBool": false
},
{
"key": "AppServiceHostLabels",
"valueString": "My Custom Domain 1"
}
]
}
```

I reviewed the [Salesforce Mobile Security Guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce1_mobile_security.pdf)  and opened a case with Salesforce that was closed because out of their scope. 
Any help or ints from somebody that may have done this before would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
"kind": "androidenterprise#managedConfiguration",
"productId": "app:com.salesforce.chatter",
"managedProperty": [
{
"key": "RequireCertAuth",
"valueBool": true
},
{
"key": "OnlyShowAuthorizedHosts",
"valueBool": false
},
{
"key": "AppServiceHosts",
"valueStringArray": 
    [
        "https://MyCustomDomain1.my.salesforce.com",
        "https://MyCustomDomain2.my.salesforce.com"
    ]
},
{
"key": "AppServiceHostLabels",
"valueStringArray": 
    [
        "My Custom Domain 1",
        "My Custom Domain 2"
    ]
}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that SF1 advertises its AppConfig incorrectly. Specifically, they seem to be publishing the AppServiceHosts-key as a type String rather than StringArray:

```
$ curl -v -H "Content-type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <redacted>"  https://www.googleapis.com/androidenterprise/v1/enterprises/<redacted>/products/app:com.salesforce.chatter/appRestrictionsSchema
> GET /androidenterprise/v1/enterprises/<redacted>/products/app:com.salesforce.chatter/appRestrictionsSchema HTTP/1.1

{
 "kind": "androidenterprise#appRestrictionsSchema",
 "restrictions": [
  {
   "key": "AppServiceHosts",
   "title": "AppServiceHosts",
   "restrictionType": "string",
   "description": "Used to specify login hosts for the application."
  },
  {
   "key": "AppServiceHostLabels",
   "title": "AppServiceHostLabels",
   "restrictionType": "string",
   "description": "Used to specify login host labels for the application."
  },
  {
   "key": "ManagedAppOAuthID",
   "title": "ManagedAppOAuthID",
   "restrictionType": "string",
   "description": "Used to specify OAuth consumer key for the application."
  },
  {
   "key": "ManagedAppCallbackURL",
   "title": "ManagedAppCallbackURL",
   "restrictionType": "string",
   "description": "Used to specify OAuth callback URL for the application."
  },
  {
   "key": "RequireCertAuth",
   "title": "RequireCertAuth",
   "restrictionType": "bool",
   "description": "Used to specify if certificate based authentication is required for the application.",
   "defaultValue": {
    "type": "bool",
    "valueBool": false
   }
  },
  {
   "key": "ManagedAppCertAlias",
   "title": "ManagedAppCertAlias",
   "restrictionType": "string",
   "description": "Used to specify the certificate alias required for the application."
  },
  {
   "key": "OnlyShowAuthorizedHosts",
   "title": "OnlyShowAuthorizedHosts",
   "restrictionType": "bool",
   "description": "Used to specify that only authorized hosts can be shown.",
   "defaultValue": {
    "type": "bool",
    "valueBool": false
   }
  },
  {
   "key": "IDPAppURLScheme",
   "title": "IDPAppURLScheme",
   "restrictionType": "string",
   "description": "Used to specify IDP app's URL scheme to be used."
  }
 ]
}
```

If anything, its the SalesForce crew that needs to fix this on their end.

Comment: Should be noted that further testing with TestDPC pointed out that the SF app is capable of listing the different server entries when changing the type to String[] and adding the entries. So the fix ought to be easy for the SF team: modify the manifest file and re-publish it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the different hosts in a single string works for me using the format below.
This will work for Intune but note that some MDMs do not allow raw JSON though so YMMV

```
        {
            "key": "AppServiceHostLabels",
            "valueString": ["Server 1", "Server 2"]
        },
        {
            "key": "AppServiceHosts",
            "valueString": ["https://server1.my.salesforce.com", "https://server2.my.salesforce.com"]
        }
```